# Mongoose - accessing data from a virtual node in 'pre' save hook

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to use data from a newly created document and use that data to update a value using a 'pre' hook.

For example, my model is:

```
...
title: {
  type: String,
  required: true
},
company: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Company',
  required: true
}
```

...

And the 'pre' hook is:

```
jobSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  const jobTitle = slugify(this.title, { lower: true })
  const companyName = slugify(this.company.name, { lower: true })
  this.slug = jobTitle + companyName
  next()
})
```

I'm not able to access `this.company` in the hook and I'm not sure how it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `company` is type of ObjectId, you can use findById to have access

```
jobSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    let job = this;
    Company.findById(job.company, function (err, company) {
        if(err) return next(err);
        const jobTitle = slugify(job.title, { lower: true })
        const companyName = slugify(company.name, { lower: true })
        job.slug = jobTitle + companyName
        next();
    });
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!